# How to make datetimepicker to control datagrid?

Tags: vb.net

So this is my code, and i trying to make datetimepicker on database mdf to controll my datagrid. There is also query code under.

```
Private Sub Date_JoinedDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Date_JoinedDateTimePicker.ValueChanged
    Me.MembersTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.KarateDataSet.Members, Date_JoinedDateTimePicker.Value )
End Sub
```

---

```
SELECT        Date_joined, First_name, ID, Last_name, Phone
FROM            members
WHERE        (Date_joined BETWEEN @dato AND Date_joined)
ORDER BY Date_joined
```

Comment: You probably want those where Date_joined > @dato (its not clear because you didnt actually describe a problem).  You also dont have to rerun a query for that - a filter would be more economical

Comment: plutnix, The thing is when i start the program this will come (An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code)

Comment: There is more to the exception message, View Details.  That info should be in the question so readers can understand the problem you have.  Error messages are not incidental.